# Numpy indexing: all rows where column value is in a list that is different for each row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a program that looks like so:

```
bar = {
    1245896421: { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    2598732155: { 31, 32, 33, 34 },
    4876552519: { 11, 12, 13, 14 },
}

# This emulates a previous step in the process, which yields batches of about 
# 1 million rows. Can't do it all at once due to memory constraints
batch_generator = (
    np.random.randint(0, 999999999999, size=(100, 5), dtype=np.int64) 
    for i in range(1000000)
)

for foo in batch_generator:

    ## This is an example of what foo looks like:
    #foo = np.array([
    #    [  1,  2,  3, 1245896421,  4 ],
    #    [  5,  6,  7, 2598732155,  8 ],
    #    [  9, 10, 11, 4876552519, 12 ],
    #    [ 13, 14, 15, 4876552519, 16 ],
    #    [ 17, 18, 19, 1245896421, 20 ],
    #])

    baz = np.array([
        row
        for row in foo
        if row[1] in bar[row[3]]
    ])
```

What I'm trying to do is to find all rows of `foo` where the value of the second column is in the set of `bar` at the index corresponding to `foo`'s fourth column. In this example, it should return rows `0` (`2` is in `bar[1245896421]`) and `3` (`14` is in `bar[4876552519]`).

The code in this example works, but it is far too slow for the scale of data that I'm working with. In my program, **it doesn't do this process with one very large-sized `foo`, but repeats the process millions of times with many small-to-mediam sized `foo`s**, which I've emulated with a random generator in this example. I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve this efficiently with Numpy.

I'm able to change the data structures for both `foo` and `bar` if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which was pretty fast for more:

```
z = np.array([[k, *v] for k, v in bar.items()])
l = z.shape[0]
mask = np.sum((foo[:, 1, None] == z[np.sum(((z[:, 0, None] == foo[:, l])) * np.r_[0:l][:, None], axis=0)]), axis=1).astype(bool)
baz = foo[mask]
```

Output:

```
>>> baz
array([[         1,          2,          3, 1245896421,          4],
       [        13,         14,         15, 4876552519,         16]])
```

#### Explanation

First, we convert the `bar` dict into a more usable array:

```
>>> bar
{1245896421: {1, 2, 3, 4},
 2598732155: {31, 32, 33, 34},
 4876552519: {11, 12, 13, 14}}
 
>>> z = np.array([[k, *v] for k, v in bar.items()])
>>> z
array([[1245896421,          1,          2,          3,          4],
       [2598732155,         32,         33,         34,         31],
       [4876552519,         11,         12,         13,         14]])
```

Next, we basically need to scale the `z` array to be the same length as `foo` array (which is the one we want to select rows out of).

Since we're using the 1st column of `z` and the 4th column of `foo` as the keys, we need to compare them:

```
>>> mat = (z[:, 0, None] == foo[:, l]).astype(int)
>>> mat
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

That matrix can now be used as indexes to repeat the `z` array to the length of the `foo` array. We can create a range and multiply the matrix by it:

```
>>> r = np.r_[0:l][:, None]
>>> r
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])

>>> mat * r
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 0]])
```

Then we can sum it vertically to get the indexes:

```
>>> repeat_indexes = np.sum(mat * r, axis=0)
array([0, 1, 2, 2, 0])
```

Now, can map the `z` array to the `foo` array:

```
>>> z[repeat_indexes]
array([[1245896421,          1,          2,          3,          4],
       [2598732155,         32,         33,         34,         31],
       [4876552519,         11,         12,         13,         14],
       [4876552519,         11,         12,         13,         14],
       [1245896421,          1,          2,          3,          4]])

>>> foo
array([[         1,          2,          3, 1245896421,          4],
       [         5,          6,          7, 2598732155,          8],
       [         9,         10,         11, 4876552519,         12],
       [        13,         14,         15, 4876552519,         16],
       [        17,         18,         19, 1245896421,         20]])
```

Finally, we use broadcasting to compare the two arrays:

```
>>> idx_mat = (foo[:, 1, None] == z[repeat_indexes]).astype(int)
>>> idx_mat
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
       
>>> mask = np.sum(idx_mat, axis=1).astype(bool)
>>> mask
array([ True, False, False,  True, False])
```

**And then...**

```
>>> foo[mask]
array([[         1,          2,          3, 1245896421,          4],
       [        13,         14,         15, 4876552519,         16]])
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation! Unfortunately, I guess I left out a key detail in the question. I'm not doing this for one very large-sized `foo`, but for many (millions) of small-sized `foo`. `bar`, however, is constant throughout the process. So, it looks like this solution might be slower, since it has to re-create the `z` array millions of times (once for each new `foo`).

Comment: Hm...could the `foo`'s be concatenated?

Comment: Unfortunately not, since that would take (according to my quick calculations) 78+ GB in memory to store that. It's a multi-step process where results from one function are `yield`ed one batch at a time to the function that does the above requirements.

Comment: Maybe you should update your examples then to account for that...

Comment: Yes, I just did. Thanks for the effort though.